# removing last 3 rows of a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a table and i have two buttons to add and remove rows to this table .

so adding row is easy (i get 3 rows via ajax every time) .

now i want to be able to remove last 3 rows of table by clicking on remove button 
so unless there is some kind of function or .... to remove recent additions to my table ! i need to remove last three rows of table myself

something like

```
$('#tbl tr:lt(3)').remove();
```

but last 3 not first ones !

or i have to do something stupid like

```
function remove(){
var i ;
for(i=0 ; i < 3 ; i++ ){
$('#table tr:last').remove();
}
alert('removed');
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$("table tr").slice(-3).remove();
```

Comment: thanx chris i have another question why this doesn't work  : 
var row_count = $(this).parent().siblings('table tr').length; 
i can get table like this but i cant get trs

Comment: Horrendous! HTML table elements have a rows collection, the simplest and fastest way (if you must use jQuery) should be `$(#tableId)[0].rows.length`, or similar.

Comment: thanx that worked now is there a way to remove last 3 rows using $this object($this refers to the button) ? $(this).parent().siblings('table tr').slice(-3).remove();

Answer (score 2):

It's not so stupid, it's a nice workaround. To clean it up, I'd use

```
function remove(){
    $('#table tr:last').remove();
    $('#table tr:last').remove();
    $('#table tr:last').remove();
    alert('removed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, it's not stupid. But if I were you, I will add a parameter, the number of rows to remove:

```
function removeLastRows(numberOfRows){
    var i ;
    for(i=0 ; i < numberOfRows ; i++ ){
        $('#table tr:last').remove();
    }
    alert('removed');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to compare with plain JS,

```
function removeLastRows(table, n) {
  if (!table || !n) return;
  var row, rows = table.rows;
  while (n--) {
    row = rows[rows.length];
    row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
  }
}

removeLastRows(document.getElementById('table', 3));
```